# adding items to listview via string.xml doesn't update the design in android but work in emulator

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

i'm new to android.i tried to make a simple activity which displays list of items but my design was not updating after i added static entries to the layout with android:entries="@array/options", but when i run my app i can see the items instead of the default one's in the layout design.

this is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/starbuzz_logo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/starbuzz_logo" />
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/options" />
    
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my screen shot of emulator and design:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ecFQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfHin.png)

but when is used constrain layout i didn't get this problem.i want to know why.also,is this problem specific to listview or does constrain layout give some advantages.